# Problem with BGP aggregate-address behavior in IOS when a large number of OSPF routes update all at once

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, bgp, cisco-ios

We have a Direct Connect setup to AWS using BGP. We are running a ISR4451 with IOS XE 16.03.06.

I have a strange situation where the AWS BGP neighbor drops our connection with the notification: `Maximum Number of Prefixes Reached` The connection goes down for a few minutes.

This happens when a large number of OSPF routes flap on our end, such as when we reboot our Cisco ASA which hosts a large number of VPN connections. This causes a large number of route changes to be sent to the router thru OSPF. AWS limits the quantity of ingress prefixes to 100. Under normal operation the number of routes we advertise are 21. We use the `aggregate-address` command to summarize the subnet that our VPN routes are on and the router receives via OSPF. So it should only advertise the summary and not the individual routes thru BGP.

However, it seems like I am misunderstanding the behavior, and it may be possible that those OSPF routes are temporarily advertised to the neighbor before they are removed and summarized?

The BGP configuration on our end looks like:

```
router bgp 65100
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 neighbor 10.100.1.1 remote-as 65005
 neighbor 10.100.1.1 description EBGP to ATT Router
 neighbor 10.100.1.1 timers 10 30
 neighbor 10.100.1.17 remote-as 65500
 neighbor 10.100.1.17 description EBGP to us-east-va (AWS)
 neighbor 10.100.1.17 password 7 xxxxx
 !
 address-family ipv4
  network 0.0.0.0
  aggregate-address 10.100.0.0 255.255.0.0 summary-only
  redistribute connected
  redistribute static
  redistribute ospf 100 match internal external 1 external 2
  neighbor 10.100.1.1 activate
  neighbor 10.100.1.1 weight 35000
  neighbor 10.100.1.1 soft-reconfiguration inbound
  neighbor 10.100.1.1 route-map bgp_prepend out
  neighbor 10.100.1.17 activate
  neighbor 10.100.1.17 weight 36000
  neighbor 10.100.1.17 soft-reconfiguration inbound
  neighbor 10.100.1.17 route-map bgp_aws_out out
 exit-address-family
!
```

The OSPF configuration to our Cisco ASA (for VPN) looks like:

```
router ospf 100
 router-id 10.100.1.10
 redistribute connected subnets
 redistribute bgp 65100 subnets
 network 10.100.1.8 0.0.0.7 area 1000
!
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but do you really need to redistribute OSPF into BGP?  I see you are already advertising a default route to AWS (I can't see your route-map which may change that).  Does AWS really need all that routing information?

Comment: @RonTrunk Obviously this description has been simplified. We have multiple default gateways, and multiple paths for different networks. That's why we use BGP in the first place. In addition, not all subnets in AWS use the default gateway advertised, but do use the private networks advertised.

Comment: When you say, "multiple paths for multiple networks", I'm wondering if you have overlooked loop prevention.  You're doing mutual redistribution (that is, redistributing OSPF into BGP and redistributing BGP into OSPF).  If you have multiple routers doing mutual redistribution with no curbs on what can go each direction, then it would be expected to have huge advertisement storms of instability when an OSPF speaker comes up and announces things.